# Asterisk beside files in Team Explorer, changes panel

Tags: azure-devops, team-explorer

We use AzureDevops. In Team Explorer, the changes area shows the modified files to check in. Some have an asterisk beside them. What does the asterisk mean? I think they are files that have been touched / modified, but are still identical to the ones in the git repository. Is that correct? They are definitely saved, unlike the asterisks on file tabs.

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Please check if my answer helps to resolve your issue, feel free to let me know if it persists to block you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Some have an asterisk beside them. What does the asterisk mean?

Normally the asterisks in changes panel should correspond to the asterisks on file tabs. See:

[image]

[image]

The asterisk besides `Program.cs` file change panel means that we've done some changes to `Program.cs` file in solution explore while we haven't save this change in file system.

Normally if we click the `Save All`(Ctrl+Shift+S) button, then the asterisks should disappear both on file tabs and in Changes Panel. If that doesn't work well in your current project, save all changes and then restart VS or reload the project to check if the issue goes away.

Comment: Lance is correct.  The * means VS considers the file buffer dirty in memory.

Comment: I had some kind of descyn between the Team Explorer and the text editor. Team Explorer showed an asterisk while the Solution Explorer/Text Editor tab did not show one (reopening the file a few times did not help). Still opening the presumably dirty file and saving it solved my problem.